# Unity Editor Window List expand together

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am writing a custom editor window that will display items from a scriptable database. I have it mostly working. the Issue i have is that when I display the list for each item. They seem to be together. For example when I expand the list it expands all of them. Not sure what I'm missing.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using Assets.HeroEditor4D.InventorySystem.Scripts;
using Assets.HeroEditor4D.InventorySystem.Scripts.Data;
using Assets.HeroEditor4D.InventorySystem.Scripts.Enums;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting.ReorderableList;
using Prop = Assets.HeroEditor4D.InventorySystem.Scripts.Data.Property;

public class ItemsLibraryEditor : EditorWindow
{
    private ItemCollection library;
    private ItemType currentType;
    //Item.ItemTypes currentType = Item.ItemTypes.Quest;
    private Color defaultColor;
    private SerializedObject serializedObject;

    private Vector2 scrollPos;


    public List<Prop> _Properties;

    [MenuItem("RPG/Items")]
    public static void ShowWindow()
    {
        EditorWindow.GetWindow<ItemsLibraryEditor>();
    }

    void OnEnable() {
        serializedObject = new SerializedObject(this);
        _Properties = new List<Prop>();

    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        defaultColor = GUI.backgroundColor;
        var collection = GameObject.Find("EquipmentManager").GetComponent<EquipmentManager>().ItemCollection;
        if(collection == null)
        {
            if (ItemCollection.Active == null) return;
            library = ItemCollection.Active;
        }
        else 
        {
            library = collection;
        }
        

        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        currentType = (ItemType)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup(currentType);
        GUI.backgroundColor = Color.green;
        if (GUILayout.Button("Add")){
            ItemParams NewItem = new ItemParams();
            NewItem.Type = currentType;
             library.Items.Add(NewItem);
        }
        GUI.backgroundColor = defaultColor;
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        scrollPos = EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos);
        for (int i = library.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            ItemParams item = library.Items[i];
            if (currentType == item.Type)
            {
                DrawCommonProperties(item);
                if (currentType == ItemType.Weapon) DrawWeaponProperties(item);
            }
        }
        EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();
    }

    private void DrawCommonProperties(ItemParams item)
    {
        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("ID", GUILayout.Width(20));
        item.Id = EditorGUILayout.TextField(item.Id, GUILayout.Width(180));
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Level:", GUILayout.Width(40));
        item.Level = EditorGUILayout.IntField(item.Level, GUILayout.Width(30));
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Name:", GUILayout.Width(40));
        item.DisplayName = EditorGUILayout.TextField(item.DisplayName, GUILayout.Width(160));
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Rarity: ", GUILayout.Width(40));
        item.Rarity = (ItemRarity)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup(item.Rarity, GUILayout.Width(120));
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Price:", GUILayout.Width(40));
        item.Price = EditorGUILayout.IntField(item.Price, GUILayout.Width(40));
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Icon:", GUILayout.Width(40));
        item.IconId = EditorGUILayout.TextField(item.IconId, GUILayout.Width(300));
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Sprite:", GUILayout.Width(40));
        item.SpriteId = EditorGUILayout.TextField(item.SpriteId, GUILayout.Width(300));
        //EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Icon", GUILayout.Width(50));
        //item.Params.Properties = EditorGUILayout.li
        //(Sprite)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(item.icon, typeof(Sprite), false, GUILayout.Width(120));

        GUI.backgroundColor = Color.red;
        if (GUILayout.Button("Remove", GUILayout.Width(120))) library.Items.Remove(item);
        GUI.backgroundColor = defaultColor;
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
    }

    private void DrawWeaponProperties(ItemParams item)
    {
        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Damage Type: ", GUILayout.Width(100));
        item.damageType = (DamageType)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup(item.damageType, GUILayout.Width(70));
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        if (currentType == ItemType.Weapon)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Properties:", GUILayout.Width(100));
            _Properties = new List<Prop>();
            _Properties = item.Properties;
            //ReorderableListGUI.ListField(_Properties, DrawListItem);
            //ReorderableListGUI.ListField(_properties, DrawListItem);
            serializedObject.Update();
            SerializedProperty CustomInspectorVar = serializedObject.FindProperty("_Properties");
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(CustomInspectorVar, true);
            if(EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck()) serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();  
            //ReorderableListGUI.ListField(_Properties, GUILayout.Height(100));
        }
        //_Properties = item.Properties;
        //serializedObject = new SerializedObject(this); 
        /*serializedObject.Update();
        
        SerializedProperty CustomInspectorVar = serializedObject.FindProperty("_Properties");
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(CustomInspectorVar, true);

        if(EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck()) serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties(); 
        */
        //ReorderableListGUI.ListField(_Properties, DrawListItem);
        //item.Properties.Add(new Property(PropertyId.Damage,value));
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
    }

    private void DrawListItem(Rect rect, int index, bool isActive, bool isFocused)
    {
        Assets.HeroEditor4D.InventorySystem.Scripts.Data.Property property = _Properties[index];
        EditorGUI.LabelField(rect, property.Id.ToString());
    }

}
```

Property Class (stripped down)

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Assets.HeroEditor4D.Common.Scripts.Common;
using Assets.HeroEditor4D.InventorySystem.Scripts.Enums;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Assets.HeroEditor4D.InventorySystem.Scripts.Data
{

public enum PropertyId // TODO: Set indexes.
    {
        Accuracy,
        Ammo,
        Antidote,
        Bandage,
        Blocking,
        BlockingFatigue,
        Capacity,
        ChargeSpeed,
        ChargeTimings,
        Craft,
        CriticalChance,
        CriticalDamage,
        CustomPrice,
        Damage,
        Duration,
        Effect,
        Exp,
        Fatigue,
        Gunpowder,
        HealthRecovery,
        HealthRestore,
        HealthMax,
        Immunity,
        Magazine,
        Materials,
        Mechanism,
        Radius,
        Range,
        Reloading,
        Resistance,
        ShopChance,
        SkillUp,
        Speed,
        StaminaRecovery,
        StaminaRestore,
        StaminaMax,
        Shock,
        Contains,
        DamageBonus,
        Multishot,
        Fragments,
        DropChance,
        ExpBonus,
        GoldBonus
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents key-value pair for storing item params.
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable]
    public class Property
    {
        public PropertyId Id;
        public string Value;
        // NonSerialized
        [HideInInspector][NonSerialized] public int ValueInt;
        [HideInInspector] [NonSerialized] public int Min;
        [HideInInspector] [NonSerialized] public int Max;
        [HideInInspector] [NonSerialized] public int Duration;
        [HideInInspector] [NonSerialized] public bool Percentage;

        public Property()
        {
        }

        public Property(PropertyId id, object value)
        {
            Id = id;
            Value = value.ToString();
        }

        
}
```

other Types

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using UnityEngine;

    [CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "ItemCollection", menuName = "HeroEditor4D/ItemCollection")]
    public class ItemCollection : ScriptableObject
    {
        [Header("Main")]
        public List<ItemParams> Items;

        [Header("Extra")]
        public Sprite BackgroundBlue;
        public Sprite BackgroundBrown;
        public Sprite BackgroundGreen;
        public Sprite BackgroundGrey;
        public Sprite BackgroundPurple;
        public Sprite BackgroundRed;

        public static ItemCollection Active;

    }
    
    public class ItemParams
    {
        public string Id;
        public int Level = 1;
        public string DisplayName;
        public ItemRarity Rarity; //enum Field
        public ItemType Type; //enum Field
        [SerializeField]
        public List<ItemTag> Tags = new List<ItemTag>();
        [SerializeField]
        public List<Property> Properties = new List<Property>();
        public DamageType damageType;
        public int Price;
        public string IconId;
        public string SpriteId;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of what I have so far.

[image: Current Screenshot]

I am currently using ProperyField which seems to be working. I tried changing them to reorderedlist (see committed lines) but I couldn't get it to display them.

*EDIT*
after derHugo update. everything working except the list will not expand items.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tv5cg.png)

Comment: Not really understanding why you go through this `Prop` list and a local `serializeObject` ... why not rather go through the SerializedObject of the according `ItemCollection`?

Comment: Generally it is a bit hard to reproduce this without having your data type structure ... you don't need to include behavior but could you add your custom types with their according fields etc as a minimal working example?

Comment: @derHugo  Added the Property class and the enum PropertyID. which is what the list is comprised of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason why both lists fold and unfold together is because they are both drawings of the exact same property `_Properties` of your editor window.

In general instead of using this local `serializedObject` of your editor itself, I would rather use and go through

```
var serializedObject = new SerializedObject(library);
```

instead and access according properties through that one.

```
public class ItemsLibraryEditor : EditorWindow
{
    private ItemType currentType;
    private Vector2 scrollPos;
    private ItemCollection library;

    [MenuItem("RPG/Items")]
    public static void ShowWindow()
    {
        GetWindow<ItemsLibraryEditor>();
    }

    private static ItemCollection GetItemCollection()
    {
        var collection = FindObjectOfType<EquipmentManager>().ItemCollection;

        if (collection != null)
        {
            return collection;
        }

        return ItemCollection.Active == null ? null : ItemCollection.Active;
    }

    private void DrawScriptField()
    {
        using (new EditorGUI.DisabledScope(true))
        {
            EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Script", MonoScript.FromScriptableObject(this), typeof(MonoScript), false);
        }

        EditorGUILayout.Space();
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        DrawScriptField();

        library = GetItemCollection();

        if (library == null)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.HelpBox($"Could not find active instance of {nameof(ItemCollection)}!", MessageType.Error);
            return;
        }

        using (new EditorGUILayout.HorizontalScope())
        {
            currentType = (ItemType)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup(currentType);

            var defaultColor = GUI.backgroundColor;
            GUI.backgroundColor = Color.green;

            if (GUILayout.Button("Add"))
            {
                var newItem = new ItemParams
                {
                    Type = currentType
                };

                Undo.RecordObject(library, "Added new item");
                library.Items.Add(newItem);
                EditorUtility.SetDirty(library);
            }

            GUI.backgroundColor = defaultColor;
        }

        var serializedObject = new SerializedObject(library);

        serializedObject.Update();

        var itemsProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(ItemCollection.Items));

        using (var scrollView = new EditorGUILayout.ScrollViewScope(scrollPos))
        {
            scrollPos = scrollView.scrollPosition;

            for (var i = itemsProperty.arraySize - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                var item = itemsProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);
                if (item.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(ItemParams.Type)).intValue == (int)currentType)
                {
                    DrawCommonProperties(item, i);
                    if (currentType == ItemType.Weapon) DrawWeaponProperties(item);
                }
            }
        }

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }

    private void DrawCommonProperties(SerializedProperty item, int index)
    {
        using (new EditorGUILayout.HorizontalScope())
        {
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("ID", GUILayout.Width(20));
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(item.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(ItemParams.Id)), GUIContent.none, GUILayout.Width(180));

            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Level:", GUILayout.Width(40));
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(item.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(ItemParams.Level)), GUIContent.none, GUILayout.Width(30));

            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Name:", GUILayout.Width(40));
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(item.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(ItemParams.DisplayName)), GUIContent.none, GUILayout.Width(160));

            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Rarity: ", GUILayout.Width(40));
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(item.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(ItemParams.Rarity)), GUIContent.none, GUILayout.Width(120));

            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Price:", GUILayout.Width(40));
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(item.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(ItemParams.Price)), GUIContent.none, GUILayout.Width(40));

            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Icon:", GUILayout.Width(40));
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(item.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(ItemParams.IconId)), GUIContent.none, GUILayout.Width(300));

            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Sprite:", GUILayout.Width(40));
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(item.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(ItemParams.SpriteId)), GUIContent.none, GUILayout.Width(300));

            var defaultColor = GUI.backgroundColor;
            GUI.backgroundColor = Color.red;
            if (GUILayout.Button("Remove", GUILayout.Width(120)))
            {
                Undo.RecordObject(library, "Removed item");
                library.Items.RemoveAt(index);
                EditorUtility.SetDirty(library);
            }

            GUI.backgroundColor = defaultColor;
        }
    }

    private void DrawWeaponProperties(SerializedProperty item)
    {
        using (new EditorGUILayout.HorizontalScope())
        {
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Damage Type: ", GUILayout.Width(100));
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(item.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(ItemParams.damageType)), GUIContent.none, GUILayout.Width(70));
        }

        using (new EditorGUILayout.HorizontalScope())
        {
            if (currentType == ItemType.Weapon)
            {
                EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Properties:", GUILayout.Width(100));

                var customInspectorVar = item.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(ItemParams.Properties));
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(customInspectorVar, GUIContent.none, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, that fixes the expanding issue. But now even though on line 154 it has includeChildren to true. It will not expand the items in Properties.

Comment: @RedWiz666 hmm .. it does for me

Comment: I updated the main post with a screenshot of whats happening.

Comment: @RedWiz666 but you can unfold these as well right? just the way it was before ..

Comment: not sure why, but I got it to work adding serializedObject.Dispose(); at the last line in the OnGUI().

Comment: no. On the last screenshot I posted. I expand the properties and then I can't expand the elements

Comment: hm that's rally weird @RedWiz666 .. what's your Unity version? as said for me it works just fine and as expected

Comment: Unity version 2022.3.0f1

Comment: @RedWiz666 ha I can reproduce it now as well .. before I had already existing items that already were unfolded before - in that case thy stayed fully interactive. But now I created the content from scratch after resetting and now I also can not unfold them further o.O

Comment: I also can not modify the inner property values like id and value .. this is really odd :/ it works totally fine within the Inspector of the ItemsLibrary directly